# Missing Messages Using the Office 365 Rest API

Tags: office365, outlook-restapi

Between the times of 16:13 BST and 17:17 BST today (5-June 2015) messages received into a shared mailbox are not being shown via the Office 365 Rest API.

Regardless of the OData queries applied I cannot get these messages to be returned via the API, it appears as if the API is completely unaware of these messages existing.

Service has resumed now however I still cannot see these messages.

I am accessing the api using client credentials OAuth flow, with full permissions to access the mailbox in question.

What might cause this to happen? Was there some downtime in the API or something else? Any information would be useful to help debug.

Answer (score 0):

That definitely shouldn't be happening. I would try moving these messages into a subfolder (so they are the only messages present in the folder), then doing a non-filtered GET to that subfolder's messages collection and see if they are returned. I'd also check doing a GET on `../folders/{folder id}/messages/$count` to see if the message count is accurate.